# XeLaTeX forces readers to rotate their heads 90 degrees

Tags: xetex, landscape

My document contains some landscaped pages using `lscape` package. When I compile the input file using `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`, the landscaped pages are automatically rotated so readers don't need to rotate their heads 90 degrees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{landscape}
\blindtext
\end{landscape}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

### Output using latex-dvips-ps2pdf

[image]

However, when the input file is compiled by `xelatex`, the landscaped pages are no longer automatically rotated, so we need to rotate our heads.

### Output using xelatex

[image]

There is a statement in `lscape` documentation as follows,

> I've made a minor improvement to
>   lscape.dtx that I'd like to share with
>   the world. My addition makes lscape
>   rotate the PDF "paper" { not just the
>   text on the page { when given the
>   "pdftex" option. (Naturally, this
>   works only with pdfLaTeX.) The result
>   is that the text is viewable online
>   without the reader having to rotate
>   his/her head 90 degrees. The document
>   still prints normally.

but when I use `\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}`, the compilation fails.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: there is a package pdflscape (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) might work better but I have not tested it

Comment: @Martin H: You should post it as an answer. (And it is correct)

Comment: To quote Michael Flanders (before singing a song about a three-toed sloth): "I really ought to be hanging upside down to sing this, but I found this rather impractical, so if you can, perhaps you'd be kind enough to stand on your head to listen and we should get more or less the right effect."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the package [pdflscape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) instead of lscape. It sets the Rotate attribute of the pdf